# Lua how to fix "name conflict for module"?

Tags: lua

I have LuaForWindows installed and simple script file containing

```
require('LuaXml')
```

works fine under SciTE or from cmd.
However when I trying to execute script containing only this line under my program using lua51.dll I have error `name conflict for module 'xml'`. Folder with script contains `lua/LuaXml.lua` and `clibs/LuaXML_lib.dll`. When I renaming this folders program stops seeing this files and I have errors like `module 'LuaXML_lib' not found` or `module 'LuaXml' not found` so lua51.dll actually looking for files and able to find. And there is no other instances of this files visible.

```
print(package.path)
```

returns `;.\?.lua;D:\Projects\Lua\FdbTool\bin\lua\?.lua;D:\Projects\Lua\FdbTool\bin\lua\?\init.lua;D:\Projects\Lua\FdbTool\bin\?.lua;D:\Projects\Lua\FdbTool\bin\?\init.lua;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\?.luac` where `D:\Projects\Lua\FdbTool\bin` is folder of executable and lua51.dll.

How to solve this issue? And, if possible, what actually this error means (can't understand from Lua docs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, it was `xml` function built-in with my program

```
lua_register(FL, PAnsiChar('xml'), funcaddr)
```

so `xml` already was in global table.